# update-database only create the _efmigrationtable in mysql database with .net core?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

**Problem:**

I am very new to .net core. So here what I am trying is to connect my .net core API to my MySQL database. For that, I have created a data model class like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace webApi.Models
{
    public class PaymentDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int  PMID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(100)")]
        public string CardOwnerName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")]
        [Required]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(5)")]
        public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(3)")]
        public string CVV { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then Db context class as this.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace webApi.Models
{
    public class PaymentDetailContext:DbContext
    {
        public PaymentDetailContext(DbContextOptions<PaymentDetailContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<PaymentDetail> PaymentDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After that, I have created this connection string and have used it in the startup.cs class as this.

```
 services.AddDbContextPool<PaymentDetailContext>(options =>
              options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
```

After running the Add-migration command successfully. when running the Update-database command it only creates the database and _efMigartion table but not my payment detail table. Can someone help me to solve this issue? I tried a lot to find out the issue but I was unable to do so. As I am new to this .net core if someone can help me to solve this issue it is really grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please check the migrations files, there will two methods called **up()** and **down()**

**up()** method should have create table migrations code for PaymentDetail

**down()** method shove have drop table code for PaymentDetail

Comment: then migrations are okay, add services.AddDbContext not services.AddDbContextPool on your startup class

Answer (score 0):

You can try following fixes.
Change paymentdetailcontext class constructor as follow

```
public PaymentDetailContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }
```

In statup.cs also change code inside configure service method to following.

```
services.AddDbContext<PaymentDetailContext>(item => item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
```

See if it solves your problem